# Фреймворк для Android Python

Tags: python, фреймворк

появился вопрос касательно Android разработки на языке программирования Python. Решил взяться за достаточно масштабный проект (какой - не скажу, не спрашивайте в комментариях) и пришло время выбора фреймворка. Мне нужен такой фреймворк, с помощью которого можно написать приложение под Android и сделать в нем большое количество анимаций, плавных переходов и т.п. И само собой должно быть большое разнообразие кастомизации, но при этом должна быть возможность настраивать под Android так, чтобы например приложение переворачивалось при повороте самого Android устройства. Подскажите фреймворк если есть, а если нет, то в каком языке программирования есть такой фреймворк.

Comment: "Переворот" приложения при изменении ориентации экрана - это, скорее всего, не свойство фреймворка. Это - на уровне самого андроида - "уничтожение" старого экрана и "создание заново" экрана в другой ориентации. А какие фремворки Вы рассматриваете как кандидаты? потому что я знаю только Flutter и Xamarin

Comment: Я рассматривал Kivy и PyQt5, но не знаю какой выбрать и подходят ли она вообще